# GLMs Limitations

Tags: generalized-linear-model

First I’ll explain the data and then the problem.

Data:

Let’s say that we need to build a GLM model to predict the income of $N$ individuals. The income variable is positive and skewed to the right, thus we assume it follows Gamma distribution.
We have three continuous predictors, $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, with $X_i \in [0, 100]$, for $i=1,2,3$. Also, we assume that they are not correlated with each other.

Also, let’s assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are negatively correlated with income, while $X_3$ is positively correlated. So after building the GLM model (gamma with log-link), $X_1$ and $X_2$ will have negative coefficients while $X_3$ has a positive coefficient.

Also, for illustration, let’s assume that $\hat{\beta}_0 = 0.5$, $\hat{\beta}_1 = -0.1$, $\hat{\beta}_2 = -0.2$, and $\hat{\beta}_3 = 0.3$,

Problem:

Let’s say that both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are large values (say, 90 and 90) and also $X_3$ is large (equals 100), then the fitted income value will be lowered because $X_1$ and $X_2$ have large values. What I want is if $X_3$ is large I need to give it more weight and kind of ignore $X_1$ and $X_2$ contributions. I feel that GLM is not appropriate here. Do you have suggestions of using other models, perhaps non-linear, and if so, what the structure would be?

Comment: If we are to assume that the model coefficients represent the "weights" of which you speak here, then no the GLM cannot do what you want, such as kind-of ignoring two other variables' contributions to the estimated effects: the GLM is a maximum likelihood procedure, and hence does not conform to beliefs (outside of the set-up of the model itself). It sounds like you wish to estimate a Bayesian GLM with an informative prior.

Comment: 1. Why would you want to give $X_3$ a higher coefficient (in effect) if it's large?  2. It sounds like what you want is a nonlinear model, perhaps, in which case a GAM might be more appropriate - especially one that can estimate some interactions.

Comment: If you derive suitable regressors and the data support your suspected behaviour, GLM might be able to do the job.

Comment: Two points: 1) from my experience, the Gamma distribution has underestimated the tail probabilities for incomes in the United States. I had to used a mixture distribution to fit the tail correctly. 2) if you need a larger weight on $X_3$ when it is larger, why not add $X^2_3$ (or some other power, like 1.5) to the model?

Comment: @AdamO That's exactly what I'm thinking. GLM is what is given in the coefficients and cannot be changed. In the Bayesian setup, how this would work? how I can inform the model that if X1, X2, and X3 are large then give X1 and X2 small weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing here is a non-linearity. From a modeling perspective, most non-linearities can be accommodated by creating a clever set of derived variables. The model which only adjusts for $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ as covariates is *not correct*. Therefore this is not so much a limitation of the GLM as it is one of specifying the right mean model.

For this answer, a caveat: large is not well-defined. Is it 40? 80? I am assuming we know what large is, it is a clear break-point, and once we exceed it, linear effects in $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are otherwise acceptable.

You can create the indicator variable: `x3large` as 0 if $X_3$ is small and 1 if $X_3$ is large. Take the product of this indicator variable with the other 3 $X_1, X_2, X_3$. The numerator degrees of freedom for the model now goes from 4 to 7. The interaction terms' coefficients represent a difference in coefficient slopes when $X_3$ is large. When the interaction term is of opposite sign but less than the original coefficient, it represents a decrease in effect. If they are of the same sign, the effect is larger in that large domain.

Per your scientific description of the trend: if the data resemble the process you have described, maximizing the likelihood is all you need to do. The interaction with `x3large` and `x1, x2` will be negative to attenuate their effect. The interaction with `x3large` and `x3` will be positive to "ramp up" it's effect.

Now I advise stopping here. If the optimal fit to the data is not as you describe, this is an interesting result. We assumed a trend and results were found otherwise.

It is possible however to fit models which are constrained to achieve effects *only* as you describe. The first method is constrained optimization. You can add a lagrange multiplier to the likelihood to offset the cases when the interaction terms are not of the desired sign. Similarly, you can conduct a Bayesian analysis with 0 prior probability on those values. The predictions from the constrained models could be compared to the unrestricted, full model to make qualitative inference on the validity of either approach.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Do you have a reference with examples for the constrained optimization method?

Comment: See `?stats::constrOptim` and search site posts. The relevant text:  Numerical Analysis for Statisticians by Lange for more details.